# RSelenium - How to click when presented with class="form-actions"

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to use Rselenium to click on a button, my standard way of clicking is not working.

the piece of html code for the button in the browser is as follows:

```
<div class="form-actions">
  <input class="btn btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="commit" value="Log in" data-disable-with="Log in">
```

I have tried all the variations to click without any success:

```
remDr$findElement("btn btn btn-primary", "Log in")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement("Log in", "Log in")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement("submit", "Log in")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement("btn.btn.btn-primary", "Log in")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement("input", "Log in")$clickElement()
remDr$findElement("input.btn", "Log in")$clickElement()
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: `findElement()` is supposed to take two args: `using` and `value`. `using` is the scheme used to find the element and `value` is the specific value that you're looking for. For example, the button you're looking for has a `name` attribute equal to `commit`, so you should be able to use `remDr$findElement("name", "commit")$clickElement()`. (Hint: use `highlightElement()` instead of `clickElement()` to be sure you found the right element)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example with link to website.